# unir datos de json php

Tags: php, json, array

hola chicos estoy tratando de unir datos de un arreglo json con php,estoy aprendiendo php,los datos resultante del json los muestro en la siguiente imagen https://prnt.sc/us8qk7 ,lo que quiero es unir los datos de 0,1,x... en un solo linea,muestro en la segunda imagen como quiero que quede https://prnt.sc/us8r47,alguien me puede dar idea de como hacerlo o si alguien ya tiene hecho algo parecido

Comment: Todo código asociado al problema presentado debe ir como texto por favor

Answer (score 0):

para que quede asi

```
 $datos= Array();

$resultado_de_consulta

foreach( $resultado as $resultado_de_consulta )
{
    $datos[] = array("miId" => $resultado["columaID usuario"], "nombre" => $resultado["columanombreUSuario"], "edad" => $resultado["columaEdad]);

}
```

y si este arreglo (o diccionario ) lo vas a mandar para que se trabej en javascript, lo haces con esta instruccion al final del archivo

```
echo json_encode( $datos);
```

y a si ya podras tambien trabajrlo desde javascript

Comment: gracias voy intentar hacerlo

Comment: Es un vector asociativo, no un diccionario, tratemos de usar los términos adecuados conforme al lenguaje que usamos